# Vague parse error message in Haskell do block

Tags: haskell, io, whitespace

Committed myself to learning Haskell over the winter break. I've written a program that takes in words, puts them into a Binary Search Tree, and then searches that tree. This is the function that handles getting words and sending them off to be searched for. GHCi is telling me there's a parse error on the line

`putStrLn $ search_term ++ " in tree: " ++ (show result)`

Full error message:
`main.hs:40:30: parse error on input ‘putStrLn’` (40 being the line number of the line above)

However, this line begins in the same column as the let expression above it so I'm not sure where the parse error is coming from, and the error message is not any more helpful than that. What's more, I've tried checking the whitespace on the lines above it, and as far as I can tell it has the same type of whitespace.  I'm guessing that it's some annoying part of Haskell's significant whitespace that I'm unfamiliar with. Any ideas? (code below)

```
search_tree :: Tree String -> IO ()
search_tree t = do
                    putStrLn "Searching:"
                    search_term <- getLine
                    putStrLn search_term
                    if not_empty search_term
                    then let result = in_tree search_term t
                         putStrLn $ search_term ++ " in tree: " ++ (show result)
                         search_tree t
                    else return ()

not_empty :: String -> Bool
not_empty = \s -> length s /= 0
```

Comment: Check this article: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation

Comment: Your expression in the `then` clause isn't proper syntax.  Should that be `then do { let result = ...; putStrLn ... }`?

Comment: Sadly, GHC's parser gives much, much worse error messages than its type checker. This is about par for the course. It seems to only have a few error messages available, and most you're likely to hit are some variant of "I couldn't parse this for some reason and I don't know why".

Answer (score 3):

The comment from @bheklilr solved it.  I should have written

```
then do
       let result = ...
```

This solved it immediately.  Thanks!